# How does the slope of a sinusoid change with its frequency?

Tags: trigonometry, slope

If I increase the frequency of a sinusoid does its slope change in the same proportion no matter what the factor I change it by? Or is the change proportionally smaller when sinusoids are very low frequency (aka almost flat)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sinusoid is given by $f(t)=a\sin(\omega t+t_0)$ where $a$ is amplitude
and $\omega$ is the angular frequency. The slope is given by the derivative
$f'(t)=a\omega\cos(\omega t+t_0)$. Fixing the amplitude $a$ but scaling
$\omega$ by a factor $k$ increases the amplitude of $f'$ by the
same factor $k$.